# Swift twitter search API could not authenticate you response, error

Tags: ios, swift, api, twitter, alamofire

When I call the api for the first time I got the expected response. However, Once I change the params value, the response appears like "message" : "Could not authenticate you:

```
var params = ["q":"fashion"]

var header = ["authorization":"OAuth 
oauth_consumer_key=\"consumer_key\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1545130242\",oauth_nonce=\"nonce\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"signature\""]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params,headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if (response.result.isSuccess){
            print("Success! got the weather data")
            let twitterJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            // self.updateWeatherData(json: weatherJSON)
            print("\(twitterJSON)")
            self.updateTwittes(json: twitterJSON)
        }else{
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error)) ")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `headers: headers` (actual variable name is header). Do you have another variable or property called headers?

Comment: By using postman everything works great whenever i change the params value i get the JSON response based on the query value. I think that authorization value is changing by Alamofire capitalization etc..

Comment: how are you changing it?

Comment: the" header" variable is passed to another function containing Alamofire function where it look like this: 
func getTwitterData(url: String,headers: [String:String] ,Params: [String: String]) 
@Scriptable

Comment: i figured out whats going on!, whenever i change the params value the oauth_signature value should be change accourding to that value, for instance for var params = ["q":"fashion"] there is a certain oauth_signature value generate by Postman api framework can be generated different than var params = ["q":"tree"]. However i'm looking for getting an automatic generated oauth_signature for a particular params value.
in the pervious example in the first time i copied header values from Postman which it provides correct oauth_signature for a certain query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TwitterAPI request should be called using BrearerToken which can be obtained by curl command:

```
        let params = ["query":"\(searchText) lang:en","maxResults":"10"]
        let headers = ["authorization":"bearer <BrearerToken>","content-type":"application/json"]
        getTwitterData(url: url,headers: headers ,Params: params)

func getTwitterData(url: String,headers: [String:String] ,Params: [String: String]){


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Params,encoding:JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if (response.result.isSuccess){
            print("Success! got the twitter data")
            let twitterJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            print("\(twitterJSON)")
            self.updateTwittes(json: twitterJSON)
        }else{
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error)) ")
        }
    }
}
```